# Getting the username (at least user's email address), after obtaining the access token for EWS.AccessAsUser.All

Tags: oauth-2.0, exchangewebservices

We are getting an access token for scopes: 'https://outlook.office.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All offline_access'.

Unfortunately, the response for 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token' doesn't contain id_token or something like this.

So the question is how to get username (an email address or unique_name) using the access token.

Comment: What is the response of  'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token' ?

Comment: `{
'scope': 'https://outlook.office.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All https://outlook.office.com/Files.Read https://outlook.office.com/Files.ReadWrite https://outlook.office.com/Files.ReadWrite.All https://outlook.office.com/Mail.ReadWrite https://outlook.office.com/User.Read', 
'access_token': 'eyJ0...', 
'expires_in': 3599, 
'refresh_token': 'OAQA...', 
'token_type': 'Bearer', 
'ext_expires_in': 3599
}`

Comment: in some cases access_token is all what you need to get the user info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I just had to add "openid email" to scopes to get id_token which contains email address.